# Haskell - Ambiguous Occurrence

Tags: haskell, ambiguous

I am getting an Ambiguous Occurrence error. I am trying to teach myself haskell and whenever I try and write bits of code, I keep getting this error.

The file name is "concats.hs"

and this is the code

```
concat    :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat xss = [x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]
```

Why this keeps happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`concat` is already defined in prelude (which is imported by default).  If you want to use the same name, you can import it as qualified (meaning you have to use a specific reference to prelude for other functions:

```
import qualified Prelude as Prelude
```

Or not import concat:

```
import Prelude hiding (concat)
```

Comment: Or using another name, like `concatenate`

Comment: This is perfect! Thankyou so much :D I didnt realise you had to import something!

Comment: Well - the problem is that you already were importing Prelude, you just didn't realize it :-).